# Excel Average grouped by another column's value

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose I have a sheet like this

```
| Interviewer | Interviewee | Score |
-------------------------------------
| Alex        | Ben         |   5   |
| Carrie      | David       |   8   |
| Emily       | Felicia     |   7   |
| Emily       | Bill        |   2   |
| Alex        | Sharon      |   9   |
```

I want to create another column which contains the average score for each interviewer. Something like

```
| Interviewer | Interviewee | Score | Interviewer Score |
---------------------------------------------------------
| Alex        | Ben         |   5   |         7         |
| Carrie      | David       |   8   |         8         |
| Emily       | Felicia     |   7   |         4.5       |
| Emily       | Bill        |   2   |         4.5       |
| Alex        | Sharon      |   9   |         7         |
```

How would I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by average of each interviewer? The average of what exactly?

Comment: @D_Zab of the score...I'll edit

Comment: use the averageif function

Comment: @gtwebb right, I can't figure out exactly how to use it. I've tried `=AVERAGEIFS(C3:C999, A3:A999,"=A1")` but that gives me a DIV/0

Comment: =AVERAGEIFS(B$3:B$999,B3,D$3:D$999), place in E3 and copy down.

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for @gtwebb. Post as an answer sot hat I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B$3:B$999,B3,D$3:D$999), place in E3 and copy down.
```